# Hammer.JS desktop text selection and swipe conflict

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I have a working implementation of Hammer.js 2.06 to use horizontal swiping to jump between pages. But I am finding on the desktop there is a conflict. When a user with a mouse selects a snippet of text, the action also triggers Hammer's swipe event.

I want to allow the default browser behaviour of text selection but also use Hammer's swipe gesture. Is there a work around to have both working together? Or should I disable mouse gesture support as the text selection ability is more important, how would I go about doing that?

```
delete Hammer.defaults.cssProps.userSelect // as suggested in tips 'n tricks
var myElement = document.getElementById("gestureCanvas"),
  nextp = document.getElementById("GotoNextPage"),
  prevp = document.getElementById("GotoPrevPage"),
  mc = new Hammer(myElement, {
    doubletap: false,
    pan: false,
    press: false,
    pinch: false,
    rotate: false,
    tap: false
  });
// gesture event listeners
mc.on("swipeleft swiperight", function(ev) {
  if (ev.type === "swipeleft") {
    if (Boolean(nextp.disabled) === false) {
      nextp.click();
    }
  } else if (ev.type === "swiperight") {
    if (Boolean(prevp.disabled) === false) {
      prevp.click();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't the use of "delete Hammer.defaults.cssProps.userSelect" actually enabling the text selection (disabled by default by hammer.js)? If user selection is not important to you I suggest you try to remove that line and see if it helps.

Comment: I updated the question to be clearer. I want both text selection and swipe gestures. Removing that line disables the text selection ability which is not desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the Hammer manager handles both touch and mouse inputs. You can instruct it to deal only with touch input, by setting the inputClass option:

```
mc = new Hammer(element, { inputClass: Hammer.TouchInput });
```

This way it will still detect the swipe gesture, but leave mouse actions like text selection alone.

Comment: This isn't working for me. Could I be missing something basic here? I haven't implemented `pan,press,..,tap' parameters that Ben mentions, could that be it?

Answer (score 9):

The accepted solution didn't work for me so I Googled and this is what I found.

> **“I can’t select my text anymore!”**
>
> Hammer is setting a property to improve the UX of the panning on
>   desktop. Regularly, the desktop browser would select the text while
>   you drag over the page. The user-select css property disables this.
>
> If you care about the text-selection and not so much about the desktop
>   experience, you can simply remove this option from the defaults. Make
>   sure you do this before creating an instance.

```
delete Hammer.defaults.cssProps.userSelect;
```

http://hammerjs.github.io/tips/

Comment: Thanks for copy/pasting